# Error cloning remote repo 'origin' in jenkins windows slave

Tags: windows, git, jenkins, slave

The question is asked already. I have seen there answers but none of them is working for me. I have changed the global configuration settings and set the git path of the slave machine. Plus I added git path in the node settings under node properties -> tool location there I added my git path too.

my git path is `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe` but the problem is still there.

Previously it was working fine but it happened suddenly.

NOTE THAT on my other windows slave it's working fine. So I don't think its any SSH key related issue.

```
Started by user Muhammad Ibrahim
Running as SYSTEM
Building remotely on ELO_122 (Group_1) in workspace c:\jenkins\workspace\Download_Latest_Version_POS
using credential GIT_HUB_SSH_KEY
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository git@github.com:aliibrahimroshan/pos_applicaiton.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe init c:\jenkins\workspace\Download_Latest_Version_POS # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:aliibrahimroshan/pos_applicaiton.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress -- git@github.com:aliibrahimroshan/pos_applicaiton.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress -- git@github.com:aliibrahimroshan/pos_applicaiton.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 130:
stdout: Process leaked file descriptors. See https://jenkins.io/redirect/troubleshooting/process-leaked-file-descriptors for more information

stderr: remote: Enumerating objects: 331, done.        
remote: Counting objects:   0% (1/331)        
remote: Counting objects:   1% (4/331)        
remote: Counting objects:   2% (7/331)        
remote: Counting objects:   3% (10/331)        
remote: Counting objects:   4% (14/331)        
remote: Counting objects:   5% (17/331)        
remote: Counting objects:   6% (20/331)        
remote: Counting objects:   7% (24/331)        
remote: Counting objects:   8% (27/331)        
remote: Counting objects:   9% (30/331)        
remote: Counting objects:  10% (34/331)        
remote: Counting objects:  11% (37/331)        
remote: Counting objects:  12% (40/331)        
remote: Counting objects:  13% (44/331)        
remote: Counting objects:  14% (47/331)        
remote: Counting objects:  15% (50/331)        
remote: Counting objects:  16% (53/331)        
remote: Counting objects:  17% (57/331)        
remote: Counting objects:  18% (60/331)        
remote: Counting objects:  19% (63/331)        
remote: Counting objects:  20% (67/331)        
remote: Counting objects:  21% (70/331)        
remote: Counting objects:  22% (73/331)        
remote: Counting objects:  23% (77/331)        
remote: Counting objects:  24% (80/331)        
remote: Counting objects:  25% (83/331)        
remote: Counting objects:  26% (87/331)        
remote: Counting objects:  27% (90/331)        
remote: Counting objects:  28% (93/331)        
remote: Counting objects:  29% (96/331)        
remote: Counting objects:  30% (100/331)        

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2430)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2044)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:81)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:569)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:798)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:161)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:154)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:97)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from 10.223.17.12/10.223.17.12:59707
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1800)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:357)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1001)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:146)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:132)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.execute(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1122)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1167)
        at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:505)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1206)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
        at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1894)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
Archiving artifacts
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: No i dont know why this happened on the same network on my other machine is working but not working on this machine previously it was working .

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue now and can't seem to find an answer... What is the status code 130 exactly?

Answer (score 2):

The following solution worked for me, the data in the repository might got increased so it is taking more time to fetch, by default in jenkins we have time out 10 minutes, so go to your job configuration page -----> under source code management---> click on Additional behaviour,in that select -----> Advanced clone behaviour, by default "fetch tag will be selected" you just need to provide 60 in "Timeout (in minutes) for clone and fetch operations", 60 is not fixed , it depends on your code, so first try this on a dummy job and see, then implement in yours.

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue for me.

Comment: Can confirm that error code 130 was resolved by increasing the clone/fetch timeout to 30 for a large repository.