# Error cloning Git Repo on Jenkins Windows Slave

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm aware that similar questions have been asked, but in my case there are some small differences.

I'm running a Jenkins pipeline where biggest part is executed on a Windows Slave. The Jenkins is master is also running on Windows.

Similar questions all point to a timeout problem. I've increased the timeout to 600 minutes so either Jenkins doesn't take the timeout into account or I'm doing something wrong. The repository is big, 1.2Gb.

What exactly is status code 130? And is there a way to get more debug information out of Git? Because I'm not seeing a timeout exception in the output... The pipeline job was actually working fine until yesterday. Now the same error keeps popping up every build.

Git version on master: 2.21.0.windows.1
Git version on slave: 2.22.0.windows.1
Jenkins version: 2.289.2

In the output I'm getting this:

```
10:40:33  Started by user Lieven Cardoen
10:40:33  Rebuilds build #646
10:50:33 
 hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\jenkins_opt\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress --prune -- origin +refs/heads/Glims_10:refs/remotes/origin/Glims_10" returned status code 130:
10:50:33  stdout: 
10:50:33  stderr: remote: Counting objects: 1           
remote: Counting objects: 4322           
remote: Counting objects: 7546  
...
remote: Counting objects: 1009788, done        
10:50:33  remote: Finding sources:   0% (1446/1009788)           
remote: Finding sources:   0% (4545/1009788)           
remote: Finding sources:   0% (8153/1009788)           
remote: Finding sources:   1% (10098/1009788)   
...
remote: Finding sources: 100% (1009788/1009788)           
remote: Finding sources: 100% (1009788/1009788)        
10:50:33  remote: Getting sizes:   0% (1496/155353)           
remote: Getting sizes:   1% (1554/155353)           
remote: Getting sizes:   2% (3108/155353)  
...
remote: Getting sizes: 100% (155353/155353)           
remote: Getting sizes: 100% (155353/155353)        
10:50:33  remote: Compressing objects:   1% (10646/899427)           
remote: Compressing objects:   2% (19153/899427)           
remote: Compressing objects:   3% (27945/899427)   
...
remote: Compressing objects:  99% (890959/899427)           
remote: Compressing objects:  99% (899418/899427)        
10:50:33  Receiving objects:   0% (1/1009788)   
Receiving objects:   1% (10098/1009788)   
Receiving objects:   2% (20196/1009788)   
...
Receiving objects:  99% (999691/1009788), 268.85 MiB | 10.80 MiB/s   
remote: Total 1009788 (delta 785654), reused 996575 (delta 774237)        
10:50:33  Receiving objects: 100% (1009788/1009788), 268.85 MiB | 10.80 MiB/s   
Receiving objects: 100% (1009788/1009788), 273.47 MiB | 11.19 MiB/s, done.
10:50:33  Resolving deltas:   0% (0/785654)   
Resolving deltas:   1% (7857/785654)   
Resolving deltas:   2% (15725/785654)   
...
Resolving deltas:  47% (369266/785654)   
Resolving deltas:  48% (377343/785654)   

10:50:33    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2661)
10:50:33    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2086)
10:50:33    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:86)
10:50:33    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:608)
10:50:33    at jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMFileSystem$BuilderImpl.build(GitSCMFileSystem.java:365)
10:50:33    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMFileSystem.of(SCMFileSystem.java:197)
10:50:33    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMFileSystem.of(SCMFileSystem.java:173)
10:50:33    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:114)
10:50:33    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:68)
10:50:33    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:309)
10:50:33    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
10:50:33    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
10:50:33  Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Looks like the job times out and is aborted by Jenkins

Comment: Then why does it timeout even if I set the timeout to 600 minutes?

Comment: [Related, maybe duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64530929/1256452) - why your timeout increase didn't take effect is not clear but I'd bet on a Jenkins bug-ette: you might have to restart all Jenkins slaves for instance.

Comment: What timeout did you set? There may be many different, and plugins can introduce them as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution in my case was to uncheck **Lightweight checkout** in configuration of the Jenkins Pipeline job.

No idea why this Lightweight checkout caused such problems because in the beginning of the Job there was this output:

```
Lightweight checkout support not available, falling back to full checkout.
```

Apparently falling back to full checkout isn't the same as unchecking the option...