# Why is Lightweight checkout not supported?

Tags: jenkins

I'm using a Jenkins pipeline project to build my sources.

When checking Lightweight checkout, I'm getting next output:

```
Lightweight checkout support not available, falling back to full checkout.
```

I'm using the latest version of Git.

Could the reason be that the Jenkinsfile is not on the root of the project?

Can't really find lots of documentation on this feature.

Comment: It's a pure Jenkins issue: Jenkins needs to learn how to do this sort of thing with Git. See, e.g., https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-62349

Comment: Thx. Strange that Git is not high on the priority list. In my case, checking Lightweight checkout broke my build. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69103349/error-cloning-git-repo-on-jenkins-windows-slave

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this error by mentioning/referring the branch name **path** (not just the branch name itself) in the configuration settings of the Jenkins job. In my case it was sufficient to have:

1. the "*/BranchName"
2. Or, "refs/heads/BranchName"

My inference from the following snapshot:

- Lightweight checkout happens when the branch refence name is unambiguous. So the Jenkinsfile can be read without performing the full checkout.
- Else it will try to look for all the branches. For this to happen it should perform the git fetch on the Jenkins server.

My reference from another question: [Does Git support lightweight checkout on Jenkins on standard pipeline jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71128315/does-git-support-lightweight-checkout-on-jenkins-on-standard-pipeline-jobs/73039895#73039895)

[image]