# Does Git support lightweight checkout on Jenkins on standard pipeline jobs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I've gone as far as checking the source code to understand the feature and how it's implemented, and it seems that it really targets multibranch jobs which has a branch source that can also provide an API way to fetch individual files. From Git perspective you can't download a single file directly from what I understand.

Checking the filesystem, I've seen that even when lightweight checkout is enabled on pipeline jobs, what happens is that the repository is cloned but no workspace is checked out. I feel that a shallow clone is happening in the background, but the job log doesn't show anything to help me understand what is going on. Tested with a huge repository and can see the cache folders on Jenkins growing to a few gigabytes. I'm using GitLab and I've found the code handling lightweight for multibranch pipeline jobs.

Is it possible to configure lightweight checkout properly for pipeline jobs? Or is it a poor man's approach of cloning and getting only the single file?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it depends in part on if your git service supports getting single files (e.g. gitlab and some others do), but I also believe their support depends on how you reference the pipeline script. The SCM branch reference probably needs to start with "refs/heads/" followed by your branch name, not just your branch name. So if your branch name is "foo" the branch specifier should be "refs/heads/foo", not just "foo".

Comment: Technically you are right and the part of being specific using `refs/heads/foo` instead of relying on Git's heuristics to match `foo` with a branch is eye-opening. But ultimately I'm interested in getting the implementation detail that Jenkins developers might be able to find out.